# collection not getting deleted in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron, mongoose

hi I am performin a deletion of my db based on the time.I am using cron to set the time and delete the db.Below is the code

```
var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new cronJob('* * * * *', function(){// set the required time
  console.log('inside cron');
  console.log(new Date());
  console.log('You will see this message every minute');
  dbDatadeletion();
}, null, true);

//This function performs the required operations after a particular time
function dbDatadeletion(){
  var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
  var db1 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/CDB');

  db1.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:')); 
  db1.once('open', function callback (){ 
    console.log('Database connectivity established...\n');
    var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ USER_ID:String, APIKEY:String, SERVICE_ORCH_NAME:String, COLLATED_DATA:String });
    var C_DATA_STORE = db1.model('C_DATA_STORE', schema);
    var query = C_DATA_STORE.find();

    console.log('Query Operation is being performed...');
    query.select('COLLATED_DATA SERVICE_ORCH_NAME');
    query.exec(function (err, data) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log('Before Deletion');
      console.log(data[0]);
      db1.C_DATA_STORE.remove();
      console.log('After Deletion');
      console.log(data[0]);
    });
  });
}
```

When i run the above code i am not able to delete my collection.Below is the error message

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined
```

Any idea how to resolve this will be really helpful

Comment: It ways that `db1.C_DATA_STORE` is undefined. Shouldn't it be `C_DATA_STORE.remove();` ?

Comment: I think that is a javascript error.  See that C_DATA_STORE is not null.   Alert(C_DATA_STORE)

Comment: C_DATA_STORE.remove() does not delete the collection. And C_DATA_STORE is not null

Answer (score 2):

To remove all docs from the collection:

```
C_DATA_STORE.remove(callback)
```

To drop the collection, use the driver method:

```
C_DATA_STORE.collection.drop(callback)
```

To drop the database, use the driver method:

```
db1.db.dropDatabase(callback)
```